# How to set text size relative to bitmap resolution?

Tags: android, math, bitmap

Hey I'm trying to write text to a bitmap, And i have no idea how to set the text size relative.

I've found some who set text size as DIP using the density, which i assume is OK
but if i try and write text on a smaller image text becomes huge.

This is the code i have :

```
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP = 95.0f;
Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
paint.setTextSize((int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP * scale + 0.5f));
```

How can i set text size to be relative to the paint size?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end i just checked what was the resolution of the images it looks good and calculated that height-width result divided to X gave me the number i wanted,
so i just divided the font by 6.
It will fail on several occasions but it's better then what i had.

Please someone answer a better solution.

Comment: why did you mark this answer as the good one if you don't think it's good enough?

Comment: It solved my problem i don't think it's good, the reason i wrote the above is because it's not a general solution, just worked in my case.

Comment: i see. i would also like to know the answer to this question . seems interesting. however , i think that you should untick the answer , so that more people would look at this question .

Comment: I did the same: bitmap.getWidth() / 20. That's not perfect since the scale doesn't seem to be the same if the image is large or small...